# Unexpected EOF in Flask

Tags: database, flask

I have a HTML textarea in which someone can place their own text. This text has to be able to support enters.
So when I submit this textarea to the database, everything works. For this example, I have put the following text in the textarea:

```
I now placed an enter. And I want to save this.

Thanks!
```

Now when I try to load this text back from the database to the browser, I get an Unexpected End of File error. See image below.

[Unexpected EOF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVfpe.png)

I have looked everywhere, but I don’t know how to fix this. The only 'solution' I can find, is to remove the enters. This however only works in Jquery/JS and not in Python (flask). Also, this is not really a solution, because the message needs to be with enters/new lines.

Could you people help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

My code (as you can see, I already tried some things):
The textarea itself:

```
<div class="col-" id="textarea-div">
   <label><b>Your message: </b></label>
   <br>
   <textarea rows="5" cols="60" id="campagne_bericht" name="campagne_bericht" maxlength="300" class="form-control" placeholder="Plaats uw bericht hier..." required></textarea>
   <script>
     // $("#campagne_bericht").keyup(function(e) {
     //   if(e.keyCode === 13) {
     //     console.log("Enter");
     //     //{# $("#campagne_bericht").val($("#campagne_bericht").val() + "test"); #}
     //     let bericht =  $("#campagne_bericht").val().replace(/[\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000-\u2009\u200a​\u200b​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]/g, 'test');
     //     console.log($("#campagne_bericht").val());
     //   }
     //   //{# $("#campagne_bericht").text($("#campagne_bericht").text().replace("\n", "Enter")); #}
     // });

     // Key Press Listener Attachment for #area.
     $("#campagne_bericht").keypress(function (event) {
        // If the key code is not associated with the ENTER key...
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // Otherwise prevent the default event.
        // event.preventDefault();
        // remove new lines from the textarea
        // let bericht = $("#campagne_bericht").val().replace(/\s+/g, '\n');
        let bericht = $("#campagne_bericht").val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '\r');
        $("#campagne_bericht").val(bericht);
        console.log(bericht);
     }
    });                    
    </script>
</div>
```

To load the text into the textarea with JQuery:

```
$('#campagne_bericht').val('{{ campagne[7] }}'); //{{ campagne[7] }} is to load the message from Python to the html.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to put multiline text in JS you can do something like this:

$('#campagne_bericht').val(`{{ campagne[7] }}`);

Basically using `` instead of ''